# How to fix: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm currently working on an API GET method with a MongoDb `$GeoWithin` query. If I check the code with breakpoints, I see that my query is returning a result. But when my application is supposed to return a response, I get an error (500) response in Postman.

I just can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. I see in the stacktrace:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'."

but I don't see anything wrong with my model/MongoDb document.

Disclaimer: my current code is quite messy, but I was just trying to get this thing to work before refactoring it.

My Model

```
public class Bag3DMember
    {
        [BsonId]
        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        public string _Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("geometry")]
        public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("geometry_name")]
        public string GeometryName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("properties")]
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }

    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        [BsonElement("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("coordinates")]
        public BsonArray Coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        [BsonElement("gid")]
        public int Gid { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("identificatie")]
        public string Identificatie { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("aanduidingrecordinactief")]
        public bool AanduidingrecordInactief { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("aanduidingrecordcorrectie")]
        public int AanduidingrecordCorrectie { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("officieel")]
        public bool Officieel { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("inonderzoek")]
        public bool InOnderzoek { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("documentnummer")]
        public string DocumentNummer { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("documentdatum")]
        public string DocumentDatum { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("bouwjaar")]
        public string Bouwjaar { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("begindatumtijdvakgeldigheid")]
        public string BeginDatumTijdVakGeldigheid { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("einddatumtijdvakgeldigheid")]
        public string EindDatumTijdVakGeldigheid { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("gemeentecode")]
        public string GemeenteCode { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ground-000")]
        public decimal? Ground000 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ground-010")]
        public decimal? Ground010 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ground-020")]
        public decimal? Ground020 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ground-030")]
        public decimal? Ground030 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ground-040")]
        public decimal? Ground040 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ground-050")]
        public decimal? Ground050 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof-025")]
        public decimal? Roof025 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof-050")]
        public decimal? Roof050 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof-075")]
        public decimal? Roof075 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof-090")]
        public decimal? Roof090 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof-095")]
        public decimal? Roof095 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof-099")]
        public decimal? Roof099 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("rmse-025")]
        public decimal? Rmse025 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("rmse-050")]
        public decimal? Rmse050 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("rmse-075")]
        public decimal? Rmse075 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("rmse-090")]
        public decimal? Rmse090 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("rmse-095")]
        public decimal? Rmse095 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("rmse-099")]
        public decimal? Rmse099 { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("roof_flat")]
        public bool RoofFlat { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("nr_ground_pts")]
        public int NrGroundPts { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("nr_roof_pts")]
        public int NrRoofPts { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ahn_file_date")]
        public string AhnFileDate { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ahn_version")]
        public int AhnVersion { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("height_valid")]
        public bool HeightValid { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("tile_id")]
        public string TileId { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("bbox")]
        public BsonArray[] BoundingBox { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<Bag3DMember>> Get(string coordinates, double radius)
        {
            if(coordinates == null || radius == 0)
            {
                return StatusCode(400, "Paramaters: 'coordinates' and/or 'radius' are not found.");
            }

            var splittedCoordinates = coordinates.Split(',');

            if(splittedCoordinates.Length != 2)
            {
                return StatusCode(406, "Coordinatesformat not accepted.");
            }

            var formattedCoordinates = Array.ConvertAll(splittedCoordinates, s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                       
            FieldDefinition<Bag3DMember> field = "bbox";
            var results = _bag3DService.GetBySpatialQuery(field, formattedCoordinates[0], formattedCoordinates[1], radius);
            var jsonResults = Json(results);
            return Json(results);
        }
```

The database service method

```
public List<Bag3DMember> GetBySpatialQuery(FieldDefinition<Bag3DMember> field, double x, double y, double radius)
        {
            //var filter = Builders<Bag3DMember>.Filter.GeoWithinBox(field, (x - (radius/2)), (y - (radius / 2)), (x + (radius / 2)), (y + (radius / 2)));
            BsonArray lowerLeftDoc = new BsonArray(new[] { 0, 0 });
            BsonArray upperRightDoc = new BsonArray(new[] { 10000000, 10000000 });
            BsonArray boundingBox = new BsonArray(new[] { lowerLeftDoc, upperRightDoc });

            BsonDocument locBox = new BsonDocument { { "$box", boundingBox } };
            BsonDocument locDoc = new BsonDocument { { "$geoWithin", locBox } };
            BsonDocument queryDoc = new BsonDocument { { "properties.bbox", locDoc } };

            var results = _Bag3DMembers.Find(new QueryDocument(queryDoc)).ToList();

            return results;
        }
```

So in Visual Studio it returns the query successfully. As you can see, it returns one document from the database:
[image: results]

JSON object:

```
{
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List<EnveoApi.Bag3DMember>",
    "$values": [
        {
            "$type": "EnveoApi.Bag3DMember",
            "_Id": "pand3d.8575483",
            "Type": "Feature",
            "Geometry": {
                "$type": "EnveoApi.Geometry",
                "Type": "Polygon",
                "Coordinates": {
                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                    "$values": [
                        {
                            "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                            "$values": [
                                {
                                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                                    "$values": [
                                        108665.593,
                                        447232.925,
                                        0
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                                    "$values": [
                                        108667.648,
                                        447229.102,
                                        0
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                                    "$values": [
                                        108676.807,
                                        447234.217,
                                        0
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                                    "$values": [
                                        108674.334,
                                        447238.579,
                                        0
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                                    "$values": [
                                        108665.593,
                                        447232.925,
                                        0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "GeometryName": "geovlak",
            "Properties": {
                "$type": "EnveoApi.Properties",
                "Gid": 8575483,
                "Identificatie": "0513100011121832",
                "AanduidingrecordInactief": "false",
                "AanduidingrecordCorrectie": 0,
                "Officieel": "false",
                "InOnderzoek": "false",
                "DocumentNummer": "BAGAV1776",
                "DocumentDatum": "2018-08-15Z",
                "Bouwjaar": "1900-01-01Z",
                "BeginDatumTijdVakGeldigheid": "2018-08-14T22:00:00Z",
                "EindDatumTijdVakGeldigheid": null,
                "GemeenteCode": "0513",
                "Ground000": -0.44,
                "Ground010": -0.42,
                "Ground020": -0.41,
                "Ground030": -0.41,
                "Ground040": -0.4,
                "Ground050": -0.39,
                "Roof025": 2.72,
                "Roof050": 2.81,
                "Roof075": 3.03,
                "Roof090": 4.76,
                "Roof095": 7.04,
                "Roof099": 9.72,
                "Rmse025": 0.87,
                "Rmse050": 0.62,
                "Rmse075": 0.62,
                "Rmse090": 0.62,
                "Rmse095": 0.62,
                "Rmse099": 0.62,
                "RoofFlat": "false",
                "NrGroundPts": 12,
                "NrRoofPts": 1247,
                "AhnFileDate": "2014-02-25T23:00:00Z",
                "AhnVersion": 3,
                "HeightValid": "true",
                "TileId": "38an2",
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray[]",
                    "$values": [
                        {
                            "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                            "$values": [
                                108665.593,
                                447229.102
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$type": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray",
                            "$values": [
                                108676.807,
                                447238.579
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get any error in Visual Studio 2019. I only get the error in Postman (stacktrace):

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
   at get_AsBoolean(Object )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Write(WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleObject(JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
 
HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:44348
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Postman-Token: c23588a0-0e6b-46f8-834c-93dbfc6134eb
```

**Edit 1:**

It seems that it works if I comment out all the nested "properties" and "coordinates" in "geometry".

So apparently "coordinates" gives me a issues. But there also documents in "properties" that is giving me issues. But I still don't understand why it's trying to cast BsonArray (which the coordinates are) to a boolean?

Also, I am now just returning the result, instead of Json(results). But that didn't make any difference.

**Edit 2:**
The "coordinates" work if I make it dynamic. But I think that's bad practise right?

```
 public class Geometry
{
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("coordinates")]
    public dynamic Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you try returning just results? Not Json(results). I think the "jsonification" is made automatically by the api class.

Comment: Can you point out what's the property that is falling to cast? Maybe you could try getting one by one of the properties of Bag3DMember (and the subproperties inside every property) until you can point out exactly what is the problematic property. That would help to solve the problem easily, I think, because I can't see the error in the model.

Comment: It seems that it works if I comment out all the nested "properties" and "coordinates" in "geometry".

So apparently "coordinates" gives me a issues. But there also documents in "properties" that is giving me issues.

But I still don't understand why it's trying to cast BsonArray (which the coordinates are) to a boolean?

Also, I am now just returning the result, instead of Json(results). But that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I just noticed this,[BsonElement("bbox")]
        public BsonArray[] BoundingBox { get; set; }
it's intentional? I mean, if it's already an array, why to add "[]"? Really asking because i want to help to solve the problem (and learn something if I can).

Comment: That was intentional yes. Is that not the right way?

Comment: Mmm, seems weird to me.It's an array inside an array?

Comment: The testing data looks like this:
``` 
        "bbox": [
          [ 108665.593, 447229.102 ],
          [ 108676.807, 447238.579 ]
        ]
```

Comment: Cool, well, I'll keep looking at the code and see if I can come up with another suggestion. Please, let me know if you find the problem.

Comment: Thanks you! Well I kinda fixed it. If I set "bbox" and "coordinates" up as dynamic, it works. But like I said in my 2nd edit, I don't think that the proper way to do it, right?

Comment: I believe Coordinates is an array of arrays, right? So the property "Coordinates" should be a `public BsonArray[] Coordinates` I believe

Comment: I believe not all the `EnveoApi.Bag3DMember` are the same format. With converting it to dynamic, you enabled all `EnveoApi.Bag3DMember`s to deserialize even with the unexcpected format

Comment: Check out what happens, when there is only one `Coordinate`

Comment: I had this problem and the workaround for me was to change my collection generic to <dynamic> and all was ok and what ever model structure will work. Example: DB.GetCollection<dynamic>("collection name");

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my workaround was to change my collection generic to  and all was ok and what ever model structure will work. Example: DB.GetCollection("collection name");

Answer (score 0):

Currently fixed the problem with the original poster suggested. using dynamic instead of BsonDocument, BsonArray or which ever your type is not working. switch between dynamic and voila!